# Вопрос по Swiper Slider. Используя watchOverflow: true, он работает, только при изменении размера окна браузера

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper

Использую слайдер swiper slider и понадобилось убирать элементы управления если слайд только один. Для этого пользуюсь watchOverflow: true. Элементы убираются всё работает, но почему то размер слайда примерно половина его настоящего размера. Как только уменьшить или увеличить окно браузера, всё становится как нужно (нужного размера). У свайпер контейнера стоит min-width:100%; но думаю это не суть важно, потому что скрипт прям в элементе прописывает нужную ширину контейнера.

Не могу найти ничего по этому вопросу. Есть только один похожий, но решения там не нашёл.

Структура примерно такая, снизу есть еще один слайдер (используется как управление основном, что то вроде пагинации там те же самые картинки)

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4">
                <div class="row">

                    <div class="col">
                        <div class="slider__images">
                            <div class="swiper-container">
                                <!-- Слайдер с изображениями -->
                                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                                        <div class="slider__image"><img src="assets/img/3.jpg" alt="" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <!-- <div class="swiper-slide">
                                        <div class="slider__image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1081"
                                                alt="" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                                        <div class="slider__image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1082"
                                                alt="" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                                        <div class="slider__image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1083"
                                                alt="" /></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="swiper-slide">
                                        <div class="slider__image"><img src="https://picsum.photos/1920/1084"
                                                alt="" /></div>
                                    </div> -->
                                </div>
                                <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
                                <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                 </div>
              </div>
           </div>
        </div>
```